# Why is this HTML5 geolocation-dependent javascript code erring?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I have some javascript code depending on geolocation.

http://jsfiddle.net/8D6vz/

```
var myLat = 0.0;
var myLng = 0.0;

function setCurrentPosition(position) {
 myLat = position.coords.latitude;
 myLng = position.coords.longitude;
}

function errorOccured() {
 document.write("sorry, error occured :( ");
}

$(function() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCurrentPosition, errorOccured);
 document.write(myLat + " " + myLng);
});
```

However, this code merely produces

```
0 0
```

instead of

```
"client's latitude here" "client's longitude here"
```

Why?

I am using Google Chrome, which surely supports geolocation. I also allowed my browser to track my location.
​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetCurrentPosition is an asynchronous function, and you can use it like

```
function GetGeolocation() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetCoords, GetError);

}
function GetCoords(position){

  var lat = position.coords.latitude;

  var long = position.coords.longitude;

  var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

  alert('Latitude: ' + lat + ', Longitude: '+ long);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I figured it out.

I believe that

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

is an asynchronous function. Hence, `setCurrentPosition(position)` is called after the latitude and longitude values are printed on the screen, which prints the original values.

Comment: Well, that was awkward. I answered my own question. I hope this question helps others who have stumbled over similar issues :) Also, let me know if you have a better answer or explanation.